# Android - Interact with the main thread every few milliseconds

Tags: android, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I'm new to Android, so apologies if I'm missing anything obvious.

I'm writing an app that does something every few hundred milliseconds. The frequency varies, but no more often than every 300 or so.

Currently I have a class DoEvery that implements Runnable that is scheduled every X milliseconds using scheduleAtFixedRate from the main thread. That is working, but I want to add an animation that is started every time DoEvery.run executes using Drawable.start() and from what I've read it doesn't seem like that is possible since Drawable.start() needs to be run on the main thread. Using scheduleAtFixedRate also seems to make it difficult to change the frequency later.

Is there a way to start the animation from the DoEvery class? Or is there a better way to run something on a regular basis like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override public void run() {

                //I'm in the thread.

                //if you are not in the Activity, pass the activity instance to your class
                // and use myActivity.runOnUiThread(...)
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override public void run() {

                        //I'm in the main thread
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
```